# Node.js How to restart Async.Series on error callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I use [Async utility module](https://caolan.github.io/async/index.html) in my app. I have a question. How i can restart the async.series, when "**get_data**" stage return an error?

```
function get() {
    console.log('App start');
    async.series([
        open_db,
        get_data,
        close_db
    ], function (err) {
        console.log('App down');
    })
};

function open_db(callback) {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/app', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('App connect to DB');
        callback();
    });
};


function get_data(callback) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error')
        callback();
    } else {
       console.log('Ok');
       callback();
    }
};


function close_db(callback) {
    mongoose.disconnect(function() {
        console.log('App disconnect from DB');
        callback();
    });
};
```

On "**get_data**" stage i use websockets.subscribe operations, and save data from another server to DB. When websocket connection down, i need to retry connection to server with some time interval

Comment: you have 2 `get_data` same function names, is that intended?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I simplified the code for this topic, and made a typo. Thank you, i fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function query_data() {
    async.series([
        open_db,
        get_data,
        close_db
    ], function (err) {
        if (err)
            ...
    })
};

function open_db(callback, attempt_no) {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/app', function(err) {
        if (!err)
            return callback();

        attemp_no = !attempt_no ? 1 : attempt_no + 1;

        if (attempt_no > 5)
            return callback(new Error('Maximum number of attempts exceeded'));

        setTimeout(() => open_db(callback, attempt_no), 500);
    });
};

function get_data(callback) {
    if (err) 
        return callback(err);

    // do-smth-with-data and call callback
};

function close_db(callback) {
    mongoose.disconnect(callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`async.retry`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#retry)

```
function all_get_data(cb) {
    console.log('App start');
    async.series([
        open_db,
        get_data,
        close_db
    ], function (err) {
        if (err) { 
            console.log('App down');
            return cb(err)
        }
        return cb()
    })
};

// try calling apiMethod 3 times, waiting 200 ms between each retry
async.retry({times: 3, interval: 200}, all_get_data, function(err, result) {
    // do something with the result
});
```